# Inverse second derivative of a Legendre transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mathematical-physics

I'm trying to find the legendre transformation of

$$ f(x)=x^3 $$

I have calculated it using the approach we learned in class:

> 1 - Find the derivative of function => $y(x) = f'(x)$
>
> 2 - Take the inverse of the derivative => $x(y)$
>
> 3 - (I) Integrate this inverse to find the legendre transformation
>
> 3 - or (II) use $g(y)=-f(x(y))+x(y)y$

I did this and my Legendre transformation turned out to be

$$ g(y)=\frac{2}{3}y\sqrt{\frac{y}{3}} $$

Which I think is correct. However, the next assignment is then

> Check the relation $f''g''=1$.

Which isn't true:

$f''=6x$ and $g''=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3y}}$

I don't understand why this should work. I could not find any information online about a relation between the second derivatives of a function with it's legendre transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:  Write $g''$ in terms of $x$, or $f''$ in terms of $y$.

Comment: Just wanted to add, in general it's a good idea to write out things like $f''$ explicitly if you're running into a wrong answer, since if you'd written it out as $\frac{df^2}{dx^2} \frac{dg^2}{dx^2} = 1$ I think you would've seen the error.